# Can I rip an Australian dvd on my Canadian machine?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, ripping, regional-settings

I have decrypter and shrink and Imgburn.

XP sp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Canadian DVDs are region 1 and Australian are region 4 ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code)) so you'd need to change the region of your DVD drive.

But you can only change the region a limited number of times. From the same Wikipedia page:

> Older DVD drives use RPC-1 ("Regional Playback Control") firmware, which means the drive allows DVDs from any region to play. Newer drives use RPC-2 firmware, which enforces the DVD region coding at the hardware level. These drives can often be reflashed or hacked with RPC-1 firmware, effectively making the drive region-free. However, this usually voids the warranty.[11]
>
> In most computer drives, users are allowed to change the region code (i.e. change region code) up to five times.[12] However, if the number of allowances reaches zero, the region last used will be permanent even if the drive is transferred to another computer. This limit is built into the drive's controller software, called firmware. Resetting the firmware count can be done with first- or third-part software tools, or by reflashing (see above) to RPC-1 firmware

There are other ways around this, but they may well be illegal in certain jurisdictions.

Answer (score 2):

You could also download "anydvd" and run that.  It's by the same people who made CloneDVD, CloneCD, etc.  It will run in the background as a service, and basically unlocks HD codecs and things of the sort for burning HD movies on non-HD devices.  However, it also unlocks the region coding for the DVDs, so you can rip/burn what you want.

I use it right now, because my wife is from Japan, and we only own one dvd player...i have to rip Japanese movies to US format for my Playstation 3 to use...so i run Anydvd, and i can watch any region dvd on my PC dvd player, rip it to a Region 0 or non-region file, and burn that to disk for use in the Playstation 3.  Here's the link:

http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll be able to it just depends on the software you use.